# sending any HTTP POST from Android to my server lead into FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, http-post, httpurlconnection

I have a server running using mongodb, mongoose and node.js. All server methods (GETs and POSTs) are tested on my HTML javascripts and they are working as intended. 
I want to make use of those methods in my android app as well. The problem: 
Whilst GET methods are responding as intended, all POST requests lead into a Java.io.FileNotFoundException. 
I have looked for tried out several ideas without success yet.
Here is the code of one HTTP POST request in my app:

```
    private class PostNewPlantTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    String responseString = "";
    int response;
    InputStream is = null;

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls){
        DataOutputStream wr=null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);  // urls[0] is the url of the http request "http://www..."
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            // encode base64 from image
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
            byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
            encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.URL_SAFE | Base64.NO_WRAP);

            // Create JSONObject:
            JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
            //jsonParam.put("loc", "["+plant_location[0]+","+plant_location[1]+"]");
            jsonParam.put("image", encodedString);
            //Log.d("POSTING PLANT JSON", jsonParam.toString());
            //Log.d("Plant loc",jsonParam.get("loc").toString());

            //wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            //wr.writeBytes(jsonParam.toString());

            //wr.flush();
            //wr.close();


            // Starts the query
            conn.connect();
            response = conn.getResponseCode();
            Log.d("HTTP POST", "#1");

            is = conn.getInputStream();
            Log.d("HTTP POST", "#2");

            // Convert the InputStream into a string
            String contentAsString = readIt(is, 1000);
            Log.d("HTTP POST","#3");
            responseString = contentAsString;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            responseString = "error occured: "+e;
            // Test: write string into textfile

        } finally {
            if (is != null){
                try { is.close();} catch (Exception e) {Log.d("HTTP GET planttypes","Exception occured at closing InputStream: "+e);}
            }
        }
        Log.d("HTTP POST plants", "The response is: " + response + responseString);



        return responseString;
    }
```

Ive added those Log.d's to narrow down where the FileNotFoundException occures. Here the Logs:

```
02-01 15:16:50.088 27382-28809/com.example.openplantmap D/HTTP POST: #1
02-01 15:16:50.096 27382-28809/com.example.openplantmap D/HTTP POST plants: The response is: 500error occured: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://www......
```

So the error FileNotFoundException occurs at

```
is = conn.getInputStream();
```

Do you know what my problem is and what I have to change in order to make it work?

The part where I call the post:

```
// Submit Button:
    Button btn_submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submitPlant);
    btn_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            new PostNewPlantTask().execute("https://www...."); // I prefer not to show the actual url here

            Log.d("SUBMIT PRESSED.","SUBMIT PRESSED");
            // TODO: GIVE FEEDBACK TO THE USER
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure that device and serwer are in the same network? :)

Comment: er... no. I'm pretty sure they're not :) Can u explain ur commend a little bit? I haven't mentioned here Im not a great Androider.

Comment: From my experience. Sometimes server is in local network and device is using 3G/LTE, so the device "don't see" server. Stupid mistake, but often occurs :).

Comment: The server is hosted by uberspace.de webspace service. As mentioned in my Question, I can make use of all those methods from my javascript website from any device. Also the GET methods which are implemented similarly as the posted POST method, are working from my android device fine. So I dont rly understand what u mean here :/

Comment: `//wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());` ???? You are not writing your data.

Comment: thats right, i commended that part out. Even uncommended I get the same FileNotFounException. No-matter which POST server method i use - even those without arguments - lead to a FileNotFoundException...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

Instead of `wr.writeBytes(jsonParam.toString());`

try `wr.write(URLEncoder.encode(jsonParam.toString(),"UTF-8"));`

and uncomment all of your lines which write to the stream.

**Original**

> The response is: 500

The response from the connection is an Error 500, or [Internal Server Error](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E500.html).  Perhaps something is wrong with your server side script, rather than your android code. I would debug from that end.

You can use the `getResponseCode()` method to determine if things go awry, and if they do, and the error code is 400 or above, the response will contain a body, which you can access using `conn.getErrorStream()`

Comment: Yes the error is 500. But the method works fine when Im doing a POST request from HTML javascript, so I assume the error to be in the android part.

Comment: Well, have you at least debugged the data server side? Make sure everything is correct when sent from Android. Also, can you post the code that is calling `PostNewPlantTask.execute(String... urls);`

Comment: I think you should uncomment writing data to the stream and debug those areas.  Looking around, I found a similar post on SO, where the user's POST request had an empty body, in turn, causing the 500 Internal Server Error.  If you don't write anything to the output stream, the POST data will be empty, and it will always give you an error 500.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Try that, and see if you still get the error

Comment: Wooooooooh! Ive got a response 400 now! Thank you, thats already more than I got from my attempts!

Comment: If you feel this answer helped you, please consider marking it correct. Glad I could help. :-)

Comment: When I finally got a 2xx response, I will do so. At the moment there must be a problem with the jsonparams. I guess the base64encoded bitmap is leading to the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102321/discussion-between-mojioms-and-andrew-senner).

Comment: finally got it to work. I had to change the content type to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8". But your answer leaded me to the right direction, so i accept it

Comment: Wow, sometimes its just that simple. XD. Glad you got. It fixed